Wont Boot and getting stuck at boot
I just installed ubunto linux and deleted windows off my lenovo ideapad, and it gets stuck booting where there is the loading wheel and then the wheel is no longer on the screen and the entire time ubunto logo is on the screen too. It just sits there and nothing happens i can open bios ive tried turning on and off settings and nothing has worked

This question is similar to: My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
